# Change colour of in-app passcode lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, lockscreen

I'm using Local Authentication to display the iOS passcode lock in an app. Does anyone know there is a way to change the colour/theme of the lock screen?

My lock screen is coming up with a white background, but I have seen other apps show a black background - which is what I would like.

**My code is:**

```
if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&error]) {
        [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication
            localizedReason:@"Are you the device owner?"
                      reply:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {
                              [_appdelegate authFailed];
                              return;
                          }

                          if (success) {
                              [_appdelegate authSuccess];
                              return;
                          } else {
                              [_appdelegate authFailed];
                              return;
                          }

                      }];
    }
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the apps which I have seen showing a different colour background have just emulated the native passcode lock.

My conclusion is that it is not possible to alter the real thing.